# Calculating distance comparing sets of frequencies

Tags: clustering, distance-functions

I have two sets of items, say A (with items a1, a2..) and B (with items b1,b2..).
Each item in A appears with different frequency with items in B, so each item would have a list of B items with frecuencies.

I want to compare items within A so that a1 and a2 are close to each other if the frequencies with the items in B are similar.

For example:

`..b1  b2  b3
a1 1   3   3
a2 3   1   0
a3 1   3   4`

a1 would be closer to a3 than to a2 because the frequencies are almost equal.
I plan to cluster items in A (maybe items in B too later) using this distances, but I understant the main problem here (at least for me) is calculating the distances between items in A. How should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classical clustering problem, and you don't need to pre-calculate distance since that is what you typically get from clustering.  If you can normalize the values in columns (b1, b2, ...) across the rows (a1, a2, ...), then any of the usual clustering algorithms (k-means, spectral, fuzzy c-means, etc.) will give you a measure of similarity.